# Upgrade from Google+ sign-in to Google sign-in in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I have a NodeJs Google cloud project that works fine and i'm using Google+ sign-in to get user profile but i got a message from google saying that Google+ Sign-in has been fully deprecated and will also be shut down on March 7, 2019.
How can i get user profil without using the methode `plus.people.get`

here is my auth functions:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

 var googleapis = require('googleapis');
 var request =    require('request');

 var client = new googleapis.auth.OAuth2(
   config.oauth2.clientID,
   config.oauth2.clientSecret,
   config.oauth2.redirectUrl
 );

 function getAuthenticationUrl() {
   return client.generateAuthUrl({
     access_type: 'offline',
     prompt: 'consent',
     scope: [
       'email',
       'profile',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
     ]
  });
}

function refreshAccessToken(tokens, callback){
  client.setCredentials(tokens)
  client.refreshAccessToken(function(err, tokens){
    console.log(err)
    client.setCredentials(tokens);
    callback(err, tokens)
  });
}

function getUserStandard(authorizationCode, callback){
  getUser(authorizationCode, client, callback) 
}

function getUser(authorizationCode, client, callback) {
  // With the code returned from OAuth flow, get an access token
  client.getToken(authorizationCode, function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    // Configure this Google API client to use the access token
    console.log("------------ getToken ---------------")
    console.log(tokens)
    console.log(tokens.refresh_token)
    client.setCredentials({
      access_token:  tokens.access_token,
      refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token,
      id_token:      tokens.id_token,
      token_type:    tokens.token_type,
      expiry_date:   tokens.expiry_date
    });
    //I bealive that this code here should be changed according to the message recieved from Google.
    // Call the Google+ API to get the profile of the user who authenticated
      googleapis.plus('v1').people.get({ userId: 'me', auth: client },function(err, profile) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
        console.log(profile)
        var user = {
          id:       profile.id,
          name:     profile.displayName,
          imageUrl: profile.image.url,
          email:    profile.emails[0].value,
          tokens:   tokens
       };
       callback(null, user);
    });
  });
}


return {
  getAuthenticationUrl: getAuthenticationUrl,
  getUserStandard:      getUserStandard,
  refreshAccessToken:   refreshAccessToken
};
};
```

**Update:** i made some changes according to the google documentation [Authenticating Users with Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users).

The authentication works fine but i can't store the users info into the session when the sign-in callback is called i store the user in the session but when the user is redirected to the original url i lose the infos that i stored.

**app.js:**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

req.session.url = "/";

console.log("********************* Default ***********************")
console.log(req.user)
console.log(req.session.url)
console.log(req.session.user)

if (!req.session.user){
    console.log("------------ No session ------------") 
    authRequired(req, res, next);
}else{

    var languageInfo = util.getLanguageJSON(req);
    var languageJSON = languageInfo[0];
    var LanguageName = languageInfo[1];

    res.render('index.ejs', {user:req.session.user, i18n:languageJSON, languageName: LanguageName});
}
});

function authRequired (req, res, next) {
  return res.redirect('/auth/login');
}

app.get('/auth/login',

(req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.user)
    if (req.query.return) {
      req.session.oauth2return = req.query.return;
    }
    next();
},
passport.authenticate('google', { 
  scope: [
    'profile',
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
  ] 
})
);


app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("********************* oauth2callback ***********************")
  req.session.user = req.user;
  req.session.user.email = req.session.user.email.toLowerCase();
  console.log(req.session.user)
  if(req.session.url == undefined){
    req.session.url = "/";
  }
  return res.redirect(req.session.url);
});
```

**auth.js:**

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: config.oauth2.OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: config.oauth2.OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: config.oauth2.OAUTH2_CALLBACK,
  accessType: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent'
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, callback) => {
  // Extract the minimal profile information we need from the profile object
  // provided by Google
  let imageUrl = '';
  if (profile.photos && profile.photos.length) {
    imageUrl = profile.photos[0].value;
  }
  var profile = {
    id:            profile.id,
    name:          profile.displayName,
    imageUrl:      imageUrl,
    email:         profile.emails[0].value,
    tokens:        params
  };

  callback(null, profile);
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  cb(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((obj, cb) => {
  cb(null, obj);
});
```

is there something wrong in my code?